# How to remove the 10% most highly predictive features in sklearn's linear SVM

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, svm, sentiment-analysis

I'm using scikit-learn's (sklearn) linear SVM (LinearSVC) and I'm currently trying to remove the 10% most predictive features for doing sentiment analysis on 3 classes (positive, negative and neutral) in order to see if I can prevent overfitting while working on domain adaptation. I know that it's possible to access the feature weights by using svm.LinearSVC().coef_ but I'm not sure how to remove the 10% most predictive features. Does anyone know to proceed? In advance, thanks for your help. Here's my code:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer as cv

# Using linear SVM classifier
clf = svm.LinearSVC()
# Count vectorizer used by the SVM classifier (select which ngrams to use here)
vec = cv(lowercase=True, ngram_range=(1,2)) 
# Fit count vectorizer with training text data
vec.fit(trainStringList) 
# X represents the text data from the respective datasets
# Transforms text into vectors for the training set
X_train = vec.transform(trainStringList) 
#transforms text into vectors for the test set
X_test = vec.transform(testStringList)   
# Y represents the labels from the respective datasets
# Converting labels from the respective data sets to integers (0="positive", 1= "neutral", 2= "negative")
Y_train = trainLabels 
Y_test = testLabels
# Fitting the training data to the linear SVM classifier 
clf.fit(X_train,Y_train)

for feature_vector in clf.coef_:
    ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Coefficients with the highest weights will indicate highest importance when generating predictions. You can eliminate the features associated with these parameters. I do not advise this. If your goal is is to reduce overfitting, C is the regularization parameter in this model. Provide a higher C value when initiating the LinearSVC object (default is 1):

```
clf = svm.LinearSVC(C=10)
```

You should be doing some sort of cross-validation to determine the best values for hyperparameters, such as C.